Why does $\sum_3^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n -n}$ diverge?
I was not able to find a function to use direct comparison with this series. $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ are both larger than $\frac{1}{n\ln n-n}$.
Using the limit comparison test does not help since $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n\ln n-n}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln n -1}=0$$

Can you compare to an integral?

I see. $ \frac{1}{n \log n}  $   is smaller than  $ \frac{1}{n \log n -n}  $

$\frac{1}{n\ln(n)-n}>\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}=a_n$. Prove that $a_n$ is decreasing and apply Cauchy’s condensation test.

@J.G. doing the integral scared me at first but I realized it's just a simple u-sub problem lol

Also, you need only compare to $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}$ rather than the harder $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x-x}$.

I did $\int \frac{dx}{x(\ln x-1)}$ with $u = ln(x)-1$, $du = \frac{1}{x}$. It wasn't that bad. But that is good to know!

As the sequence $a_n=n\ln(n)-n=n(\ln(n)-1)$ is monotone and $a_n>0$, we can use the following test: $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if the sum $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converges. We get
$b_n=2^na_{2^n}=2^n\dfrac{1}{2^n(\ln(2^n)-1)}=\dfrac 1{\ln(2)n-1}$. This sum diverges.
The test follows from the following inequality
$2(a_{2^{n-1}+1}+\dots+ a_{2^n}) \leq 2^na_{2^n}\leq a_{2^n+1}+\dots+a_{2^{n+1}} $.

You should give a reference or some background for the test you are using.

Just do the integral test
$$ \int_{2}^\infty \frac{dx}{x\ln (x)-x}= \int_{2}^\infty \frac{dx}{x(\ln (x)-1)}= \int_{\ln(2)}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u-1} = \ln (+\infty-1) -\ln(\ln(2)-1) \to +\infty$$
so the series diverges
